# Swagger-ui only sending OPTIONS not POST http method despite working API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, post, swagger, grape-api

I am using Swagger-UI to browse my own API, built with grape and automatically documented with grape-swagger.

I've googled and tried every suggestion I can find, but I cannot get POST to work.  Here's my headers:

```
  header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
  header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  header "Access-Control-Request-Method", "*"
  header "Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000"
  header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "api_key, Content-Type"
```

I just threw in everything suggested.  I've enabled all the HTTP methods in supportedSubmitMethods and I have tested the API using the POSTMAN Chrome extension and it works perfectly.  Creates a user  properly and returns the correct data.

However all I get with swagger post is the server reporting:

```
Started OPTIONS "/v1/users.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-21 04:07:13 -0800
```

and swagger response looking like this:

Request URL

```
http://api.lvh.me:3000/v1/users.json
```

Response Body

Response Code

```
0
```

Response Headers

I have also tested the OPTIONS response with POSTMAN and it is below:

```
Allow →OPTIONS, GET, POST
Cache-Control →no-cache
Date →Fri, 21 Dec 2012 12:14:27 GMT
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Request-Id →9215cba8da86824b97c6900fb6d97aec
X-Runtime →0.170000
X-UA-Compatible →IE=Edge
```

Comment: did you solve it? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: to be honest i cannot remember if i solved it or put it on the shelf - i'll take another look today and report back Neha

Comment: it worked. I provided it a domain name and changed the basePath to the domain name.

Comment: That's awesome news... so if you have an answer, post it, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and just solved it, hope this helps somebody.

Swagger-UI accepts multiple parameters through POST only through a 'form' paramType, not 'body' paramType, referenced in this issue https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui/issues/72.

I used the branch :git => 'git://github.com/Digication/grape-swagger.git' changing 'post' request paramType to 'form'. Generated xml output for swagger_doc (probably at path/swagger_doc/api or similar) should look something like this:

```
<api>
  <path>/api/v2/...</path>
    <operations type="array">
      ...
      <httpMethod>POST</httpMethod>
        <parameters type="array">
          <parameter>
            <paramType>form</paramType>
            ...More
```

Not

```
<paramType>body</paramType>
...More
```

I used the grape-swagger-rails gem to automatically install swagger-ui on localhost (files can also be downloaded from the swagger-ui site), and everything works!!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Fixed by adding CORS

add into Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

add into application.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      # location of your API
      resource '/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :put]
    end
end
```

be sure that you've changed location of your API here.

Answer (score 0):

Nice to hear you are using grape-swagger: I think it is awesome :)

I am not entirely sure you are having the same problem, but when testing locally from the browser it will try to check if the origin is the same as requested, so to make sure I do not get that error, I created a small middleware that will tell the browser we allow all origin.

I am using a rails process (created with the awesome rails-api gem), so I create a new file in `lib/middleware/access_control_allow_all_origin.rb` with the following content:

```
module Middleware
  class AccessControlAllowAllOrigin

    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
      allow_all_origin!(headers)
      [status, headers, body]
    end

    private

    def allow_all_origin!(headers)
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    end

  end
end
```

and at the bottom of my `application.rb` I just add the middleware as follows:

```
require 'middleware/access_control_allow_all_origin'
config.middleware.insert_after Rack::ETag, Middleware::AccessControlAllowAllOrigin
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not the CORS issue that I'm getting - though that was an earlier problem that I'd had with this.  I put this on the back burner to focus on other parts of the problem so I'll take a fresh look at this this week.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the solution for `ruby-on-rails` as I am using Swagger with `play framework 2.0.2`. 
I provided a domain name to it and changed the basePath to domain name in application.conf file as `swagger.api.basepath="domain-name"` and it worked.
You can change the `basePath` in `api-docs` to `domain-name`. I read about the `api-docs` on 
[api-docs](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/ruby-source2swagger/public/api-docs).

Comment: oh - that's interesting - okay let me check this out then with my Rails implementation within the next 24 hours - if works I'll click the checkmark and upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

And does your web server hijack headers? If you are using NGinx for example, your "OPTIONS" request might not send the appropriate values as a response, in some cases.

What is your OPTIONS request response? Can you dump it out here? I'll tell you if it can be that.

Comment: This is a good question. I haven't ignored it. Just need to get a chance to check as I've not looked at this in a whole. The testing was just local host and I cannot recall which server I was using for that - ill check and update this.